# How "gradually" do the effects of the Control Weather spell fade?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, time, weather

The [*control weather*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/control-weather) spell description (PHB p. 288) states that "When the spell ends, the weather gradually returns to normal."

While it gives a specific duration for each tier of effect, it leaves the return to normal up to interpretation. Does it change in a matter of minutes or hours? Or could it be days or even weeks before the weather recovers from the change you've inflicted on it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since the duration is not specified it is up to the GM.

However, I'd focus on two points (emphasis mine):

> When you cast the spell, you change the current weather conditions,
>   which are determined by the DM based on the climate and season. You
>   can change precipitation, temperature, and wind. **It takes 1d4 × 10
>   minutes for the new conditions to take effect.** Once they do so, you
>   can change the conditions again. **When the spell ends, the weather
>   gradually returns to normal.**

and

> When you change the weather conditions, find a current condition on
>   the following tables and **change its stage by one**, up or down. When
>   changing the wind, you can change its direction.

Based on the above I understand two things:

1. If the weather has been changed more than one time (e.g., warm -> cool -> cold) then when the effects are reversed the same order should be followed (i.e., cold -> cool -> warm), otherwise the change is not "gradual".
2. The fastest effect can be achieved in 1 x 10 minutes. The slowest in 4 x 10 minutes. Thus, a gradual change of ***one stage*** should be anything between 10 and 40 minutes. Personally, I'd go for 20 minutes per stage but you can also ask the player to roll.

Comment: I agree, the most straightforward ruling is to just take "1d4 × 10 minutes per stage" as the implied definition of gradual.

Comment: That is how I ruled it in session the other day, but wondered if I had missed something in the spell's description. Thank you!